# Same code differs in output across IDE's & pyshell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I was running this code on VScode.

```
 age_1 = int(input("age : "))
 print(age_1)
```

It shows this at it's terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'print(age_1)
```

In Pycharm it shows this output after taking input as 12 :

```
age : 12
12
```

In PyShell it works like the Pycharm one. What did I do wrong in the VScode ?

**Update :**
When ran on a new file on VScode, it ran properly like the Pycharm one. But only for once . Then it shows up same error like before along with some new kinds of error everytime it ran.

Here's the correct one in VScode when ran the 1st time.

```
PS I:\CSE\LEARNING\PYTHON 3.0\practice> & "C:/Users/Alvi Adhikary Niloy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "i:/CSE/LEARNING/PYTHON 3.0/practice/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
age : 12
12
```

Here's one error when ran another time.

```
& "C:/Users/Alvi Adhikary Niloy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "i:/CSE/LEARNING/PYTHON 3.0/practice/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & "C:/Users/Alvi Adhikary Niloy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "i:/CSE/LEARNING/PYTHON 3.0/practice/tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's another error :

```
 >>>print(age_1)                         age1 = int(input("age : "))
      File "<stdin>", line 1
        print(age_1)                         age1 = int(input("age : "))
                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

& here's the final one .

```
>>> print(age1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'age1' is not defined
```

**P.S.** I ain't skilled in coding. Explaining with some codes patiently will be appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

The Python ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 error is raised when you try to convert a string value that is not formatted as an integer. ... Then, you can use int() to convert your number to an integer. If this does not work, make sure that the value of a string does not contain any letters.I think you wrote a word that does not change int in the input.  Maybe it's a space

Comment: Explaining with some code examples will be nice . I still am not getting your answer completely, I apologize. But my point is, if there's an error why did it ran on other IDE's ? Also, why did it ran on VScode now(though only for once) ?

Comment: It also works in vscode but you typed str when the input came in and it was not possible to convert it to int.